# Pull Active Directory Country/region list into C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is there a way to pull all the Countries that are listed in Active Directories Country\region drop down selection under the "Users" Address Properties into .Net C#.

I would like to get all the 'display names' along with there 'two character country abbreviation'.

Below is a picture of the drop down I'm referring to

[image: AD User Properties]

I would like to have a similar list in my app to select countries from which I can create AD users with, 
I can't hard code the list because it needs to match the AD language of whatever server it's running on.

If I'm not being clear please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<string> countries = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Select(lang => new System.Globalization.RegionInfo(lang.LCID).DisplayName);
```

.Net automatically handles the culture, so if you run the above with the operating system language set to french, all of the country names will be returned in french.